# How can users delete their Server Fault user profiles?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account)

How can users delete their Server Fault user profiles?

Comment: Instructions at [Can I delete my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account) are applicable to all of the sites.

Answer (score 0):

In the FAQ

[How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account)

Comment: Thanks. Bad there is no red button "delete". Boring three steps.

Comment: @topright You can always put in a feature request (or search for a similar open FR) on Meta.

Comment: ...although ironically you'll need an account for that :)

Comment: @David Perhaps the same account which they used to originally post the question on SF?  :)