# How can I find a question migrated to meta?

Tags: support, migration

How can I find a question migrated to meta? https://serverfault.com/questions/157016/delete-my-serverfault-user-profile-closed

Answer (score 2):

Just click on the link in the "migrated to [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55754/delete-my-serverfault-user-profile) by..." field of the original question.

Comment: In addition to this, in the case where you do have a Meta account associated with the account on the other site, you gain ownership of the question, and it will be listed in your profile exactly as if you had asked it.